# flattern nested list with uneven column numbers into data frame in R

Tags: r, list, recursion

I face a challenge of binding a nested list into a dataframe for processing.

Edit: here below is the example of original nested data before I tried to flat them.

```
list(list(list(url = "https://lda.senate.gov/api/v1/filings/5e4bbd96-db94-4ea3-a310-7a7fb1e93fff/", 
    filing_uuid = "5e4bbd96-db94-4ea3-a310-7a7fb1e93fff", filing_type = "Q1", 
    filing_type_display = "1st Quarter - Report", filing_year = 2021L, 
    filing_period = "first_quarter", filing_period_display = "1st Quarter (Jan 1 - Mar 31)", 
    filing_document_url = "https://lda.senate.gov/filings/public/filing/5e4bbd96-db94-4ea3-a310-7a7fb1e93fff/print/", 
    filing_document_content_type = "text/html", income = "15000.00", 
    expenses = NULL, expenses_method = NULL, expenses_method_display = NULL, 
    posted_by_name = "Christian Smith", dt_posted = "2021-04-30T10:20:59.217000-04:00", 
    termination_date = NULL, registrant = list(id = 8214L, url = "https://lda.senate.gov/api/v1/registrants/8214/", 
        house_registrant_id = 31113L, name = "CAPSTONE NATIONAL PARTNERS", 
        description = "public affairs", address_1 = "501 Capitol Court NE", 
        address_2 = "Suite 100", address_3 = NULL, address_4 = NULL, 
        city = "Washington", state = "DC", state_display = "District of Columbia", 
        zip = "20002", country = "US", country_display = "United States of America", 
        ppb_country = "US", ppb_country_display = "United States of America", 
        contact_name = "", contact_telephone = "", dt_updated = "2022-01-13T14:47:31.828778-05:00"), 
    client = list(id = 111342L, url = "https://lda.senate.gov/api/v1/clients/111342/", 
        client_id = 303L, name = "OSHKOSH CORPORATION", general_description = "manufacturing", 
        client_government_entity = FALSE, client_self_select = NULL, 
        state = "WI", state_display = "Wisconsin", country = "US", 
        country_display = "United States of America", ppb_state = "WI", 
        ppb_state_display = "Wisconsin", ppb_country = "US", 
        ppb_country_display = "United States of America", effective_date = "2016-04-01"), 
    lobbying_activities = list(list(general_issue_code = "BUD", 
        general_issue_code_display = "Budget/Appropriations", 
        description = "FY22 Appropriations", foreign_entity_issues = "", 
        lobbyists = list(list(lobbyist = list(id = 63767L, prefix = NULL, 
            prefix_display = NULL, first_name = "WILLIAM", nickname = NULL, 
            middle_name = NULL, last_name = "STONE", suffix = NULL, 
            suffix_display = NULL), covered_position = "Chief of Staff, Dave Obey: House Appropriations Committee", 
            new = FALSE)), government_entities = list(list(id = 2L, 
            name = "HOUSE OF REPRESENTATIVES"), list(id = 1L, 
            name = "SENATE")))), conviction_disclosures = list(), 
    foreign_entities = list(), affiliated_organizations = list())), 
    list(list(url = "https://lda.senate.gov/api/v1/filings/177b995a-3be2-4127-b962-795e76974617/", 
        filing_uuid = "177b995a-3be2-4127-b962-795e76974617", 
        filing_type = "Q1", filing_type_display = "1st Quarter - Report", 
        filing_year = 2021L, filing_period = "first_quarter", 
        filing_period_display = "1st Quarter (Jan 1 - Mar 31)", 
        filing_document_url = "https://lda.senate.gov/filings/public/filing/177b995a-3be2-4127-b962-795e76974617/print/", 
        filing_document_content_type = "text/html", income = "22500.00", 
        expenses = NULL, expenses_method = NULL, expenses_method_display = NULL, 
        posted_by_name = "Doyce Boesch", dt_posted = "2021-04-30T11:22:12.233000-04:00", 
        termination_date = NULL, registrant = list(id = 400677020L, 
            url = "https://lda.senate.gov/api/v1/registrants/400677020/", 
            house_registrant_id = NULL, name = "MR. DOYCE BOESCH", 
            description = "Government Relations", address_1 = "4515 W Street NW", 
            address_2 = NULL, address_3 = NULL, address_4 = NULL, 
            city = "Washington", state = "DC", state_display = "District of Columbia", 
            zip = "20007", country = "US", country_display = "United States of America", 
            ppb_country = "US", ppb_country_display = "United States of America", 
            contact_name = "DOYCE BOESCH", contact_telephone = "+1 202-731-9995", 
            dt_updated = "2022-01-13T14:59:12.412096-05:00"), 
        client = list(id = 194057L, url = "https://lda.senate.gov/api/v1/clients/194057/", 
            client_id = 75L, name = "INVESTMENT COMPANY INSTITUTE", 
            general_description = "Stock Market and Financial Services", 
            client_government_entity = FALSE, client_self_select = FALSE, 
            state = "DC", state_display = "District of Columbia", 
            country = "US", country_display = "United States of America", 
            ppb_state = NULL, ppb_state_display = NULL, ppb_country = "US", 
            ppb_country_display = "United States of America", 
            effective_date = "2012-07-01"), lobbying_activities = list(
            list(general_issue_code = "FIN", general_issue_code_display = "Financial Institutions/Investments/Securities", 
                description = "providing awareness of members positions", 
                foreign_entity_issues = "", lobbyists = list(
                  list(lobbyist = list(id = 52828L, prefix = NULL, 
                    prefix_display = NULL, first_name = "DOYCE", 
                    nickname = NULL, middle_name = NULL, last_name = "BOESCH", 
                    suffix = NULL, suffix_display = NULL), covered_position = NULL, 
                    new = FALSE)), government_entities = list(
                  list(id = 2L, name = "HOUSE OF REPRESENTATIVES"), 
                  list(id = 1L, name = "SENATE")))), conviction_disclosures = list(), 
        foreign_entities = list(), affiliated_organizations = list())))
```

So taking this highly nested data, call it

```
my.data
```

then I tried to flatten it by

```
flat.df <- lapply(my.data, function(i) list(unlist(i, recursive = F)))
```

it sort of worked, but still each element in the flat.df list still have multiple sublists, for example "lobbying_activities", "lobbyists". And they are not expaned(I want the information inside).

But if I set recursive to "TRUE", then the flattened list have duplicated columns and most frustratingly I see some columns got lumped together (for example people's name got into expense column)

Ideally I want to flat such sublists in each table and make the whole thing in one table. Then join them into a dataframe by

```
df<- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", flat.df))
```

Comment: Could you specify how you got to this point? What is the original shape of your data? I suspect an XY problem, where changing how data is read in might prevent (for example by reading JSON to `tibble` with a nested list for lobbyist variables) this flattening issue.

Comment: @DonaldSeinen thank you for the reply. I never dealt with json file before and I felt you are on point. I did read in the files by using REST API and results are parsed by using httr::content. From there I get a very nested list, so I used lapply(my.results, function(i) list(unlist(i, recursive = TRUE))) to unlist them, and assemble each one into a list. I will add the original data

Comment: @DonaldSeinen I have uploaded the original nested list after API data parsing. Sorry for the confusion, I'm too green I know. I hope this make sense now

Comment: don't worry, nobody on SO is too green. What would your ideal output look like? That is often a good starting point to tackle problems. For this one, I think `unlist(l, recursive = F)` > identify duplicate list element positions > build dataframe from non-duplicate name elements > add columns for nested elements would be a good approach.

Comment: @DonaldSeinen Thank you. So the big picture is : In the original highly nested list, each element is a filing report, and the sublists inside each list are the details of that report. I would like to flat them into a table. And then do so for each filing report. Since at the original highly nested list level, they should all have the same col names, I can then just bind them all into a big dataframe. Then this whole set will be repeated quarterly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tibble`s are a nice format, as they support nested data.frames. I would aim for a tibble with 2 rows, a wide format. In it, each nested list element would be its own data.frame, which we could manipulate later when needed. I would do something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
l = unlist(l, recursive = F)
ind_to_nest <- which(map_lgl(l[[1]], is.list))
non_tbl <- map(l, ~ .x[-ind_to_nest])
tbl <- map(l, ~ .x[ind_to_nest])

df <- bind_rows(non_tbl) %>%
  mutate(n = 1:n(), .before = 1) %>%
  mutate(data =  map(tbl,  ~ map(.x, ~flatten(.x) %>% bind_cols))) %>%
  unnest_wider(data, simplify = F)
```

Note that this does throw a bunch of warnings. This is because of the name conflicts present within the list.

```
#> New names:
#> * id -> id...5
#> * id -> id...10
```

Can be resolved by specifying a naming policy, or by rethinking how the data is read into R to resolve naming conflicts early.

```
#> Outer names are only allowed for unnamed scalar atomic inputs
```

This is a bit tougher to resolve, but this [issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/165) is a starting point.

For analysis some cleaning of sub-tibbles can be performed when needed, as different tasks require different shapes.

Comment: "In it, each nested list element would be its own data.frame, which we could manipulate later when needed". How do I manipulate that? For example in your code, "lobbying activities" is a nested list in the formatted tibble, how do I expand that? Can I have the "lobbying activities" of Christian Smith (row 1), expand into a dataframe but having Christian Smith in there as a label?

Comment: @ML33M Nested data.frames can be manipulated as if they were a vector by using the `*apply` or in tidyverse syntax `purrr`-style functions. These apply a function to each element of a list. If your use case is to work with a few variables within that nested data.frame, another option is to rectangle the data. For example `df %>% select(posted_by_name, lobbying_activities) %>% unnest_wider(lobbying_activities)`.

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you for the teaching! I get it to work!!